# C#, Create GPO And link it to OU using Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management?

Tags: c#, hyperlink, gpo, ou

I've done hard research and trying to solve my problem. 3 days googling and asking now i ended up with this :

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;

private void ManipulateGPO(){
    GPDomain domain = new GPDomain("sh.dom");
    Gpo gpo_background = domain.CreateGpo("testingGPO");
}
```

the code above create a GPO successfully. but i need to link it to an OU?

any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE 1:
[My GPO Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFk3c.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the SOM (Scope of Management) class to link to the OU

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;

private void ManipulateGPO(){
    GPDomain domain = new GPDomain("sh.dom");
    Gpo gpo_background = domain.CreateGpo("testingGPO");
    Som som = domain.GetSom("The path of the SOM specified as a fully qualified distinguished name, for example, (ou=MyOU,dc=contoso,dc=com)");
    som.LinkGpo(-1, gpo_background);
}
```

References
Som Class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.grouppolicy.som(v=vs.85).aspx

LinkGpo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.grouppolicy.som.linkgpo(v=vs.85).aspx

GPDomain.GetSom: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.grouppolicy.gpdomain.getsom(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for reply. can you please tell me how can i exactly format the strOU string. i posted a screenshot of my gpo structure.

Comment: Should be: ou=IT,dc=SH,dc=dom

Comment: the "IT" ou is under "sh divisions", and shouldn't be like "ou=sh divisions, ou=IT, dc=sh, dc=dom" ??   @sorceri

Comment: @KhaledRakhisi yes you are correct, you can find out the name by going to Active directory users and computers snap-in-> Right Click the OU -> Properties -> AttributeEditor -> DistinguishedName

Comment: i filled strOU with: 
LDAP://sh/ou=Dahan o Dandan,ou=Markaz_Behdasht,DC=sh,DC=dom
now it throw an error on line :
Som som = domain.GetSom(sOU);
and says:
Value does not fall within the expected range

Comment: @KhaledRakhisi  look here, https://serverfault.com/questions/130543/how-can-i-figure-out-my-ldap-connection-string