# How to programmatically add a new path rule in software restriction policy in a newly created GPO?

Tags: c#, winapi, active-directory, group-policy, gpo

I was able to add a GPO to the domain using the example provided in [C#, Create GPO And link it to OU using Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553917/c-create-gpo-and-link-it-to-ou-using-microsoft-grouppolicy-management) . However editing the GPO to add a new path rule is confusing. Some sources say to add registry values and update the gpo, but I am having trouble editing the GPO

I am able to create a GPO, but stuck with modifying the GPO to accommodate software restriction policies. I have seen a method somewhere which involves making a .inf file and updating details in it and then updating the GPO.

I have created a sample GPO(manually), but the inf file doesn't contain any configuration details.

New Policy with software restriction policy added to block C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe

[image]

Corresponding registry value changes(RegistrySetValue) taken from process monitor.

[image]

The corresponding entry in RegEdit

[image]

How can I replicate this using code?

I found this link https://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2013/03/25/programmatically-updating-local-policy-in-windows/ where the author said adding gpo was possible when suitable registry keys are correctly created. Even it is local gpo, I couldn't get it to work even on local gpo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IGroupPolicyObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gpedit/nn-gpedit-igrouppolicyobject) interface.

This document explains in deep about accessing Group Policies programmatically and provide the samples:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsadsi/2009/07/23/working-with-group-policy-objects-programmatically-simple-c-example-illustrating-how-to-modify-a-registry-based-policy/